Unexpected 'xmlns' attribute in serialized XML
I'm trying to generate XSPF (XML) in JavaScript, and display the generated code in a <pre> block on a webpage. This is for a web app that creates music playlists.

This is the JS code I'm currently experimenting with:
    const xspfTemplate = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
    <trackList>
    </trackList>
</playlist>`;
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    xspfDoc = parser.parseFromString(xspfTemplate, 'text/xml');

    let track = xspfDoc.createElement('track');
    let location = xspfDoc.createElement('location');
    location.textContent = encodeURIComponent('my album/my music.mp3');
    track.append(location);
    xspfDoc.querySelector('trackList').append(track);

    let xspfString = serializer.serializeToString(xspfDoc);
    xspfOutput.append(xspfString);

After investigating with the Firefox debugger, it appears to me that the serialization step is adding an empty xmlns attribute to the <track> element.
Actual output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
    <trackList>
    <track xmlns=""><location>my%20album%2Fmy%20music.mp3</location></track></trackList>
</playlist>

Expected output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
    <trackList>
    <track><location>my%20album%2Fmy%20music.mp3</location></track></trackList>
</playlist>

My reference for handling XML in JavaScript

Failing to specify that track is in the default namespace results in it being placed in no namespace and is causing the undesired xmlns="".  To correct this, rather than createElement() use createElementNS() to place track and location elements into the default http://xspf.org/ns/0/ namespace.
Change
let track = xspfDoc.createElement('track');
let location = xspfDoc.createElement('location');

to
const ns = 'http://xspf.org/ns/0/';
const track = xspfDoc.createElementNS(ns, 'track');
const location = xspfDoc.createElementNS(ns, 'location');


Thanks, that fixed it. Any comments on how I'm generating XML? I don't know if this is the best way to do it. How would you do it?

Won't elaborate further here as comments are not the place for design discussions, but another approach would be to populate and build out your XML entirely via JS template literals.
